# Is it a good practice initialising ViewController inside of prepare for segue method?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mvvm, architecture

I have 3 classes: MyProfileVC, NewProfileVC and NewProfileViewModel.
To make my tests writing easier I decided to create initialisers in my last 2 classes like this:

NewProfileViewController:

```
var user: Users
var viewModel: NewProfileViewModel

init(for user: Users, with coreDataStack: CoreDataStack) {
    self.user = user
    self.viewModel = NewProfileViewModel(for: user, with: coreDataStack)

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

where `NewProfileViewModel` has its own init:

```
var user: Users
var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack

init(for user: Users, with coreDataStack: CoreDataStack) {
    self.user = user
    self.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
}
```

And at the end I'm trying to initialize both of them as a chain from `MyProfileViewController` as:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toNewProfile" {
        var viewController = segue.destination as! NewProfileViewController
        viewController = NewProfileViewController(for: sender as? Users ?? Users(context: coreDataStack.mainContext), with: coreDataStack)            
    }
}
```

So this will initialize my `NewProfileVC` and the `NewProfileVC` will init `NewProfileViewModel`.

But I want to ask the developers with higher experience than I have, is it a good practice to initialize VC inside of `prepare: for segue` in that way what I just did or you can give me better ideas?
I do not want to write the code what simply works but want to build a good architecture and I do not have any mentor to ask him about, so the only place is Stack and I hope you will help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `init`, use a `configure(for:with:)` or something like that. Because `segue.destination as! NewProfileViewController` should already be a "init" (initWithCoder: should be called) since it's in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** initialize a new view controller in `prepareForSegue`.

The [purpose of this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue) is *to **configure** the new view controller prior to it being displayed*. (emphasis added).

The segue gives you an *initialized* destination view controller. It's important to use this instance so that all the outlets and actions you defined in the storyboard are set up correctly. This will not be the case for a view controller initialized in the manner you showed.

To pass data to your view controller, define the data variables as optionals in your `NewProfileViewController`:

```
var user: Users?
var viewModel: NewProfileViewModel?
```

and set them in `prepareForSegue`:

```
if segue.identifier == "toNewProfile" {
    var viewController = segue.destination as! NewProfileViewController
    var user = Users ?? Users(context: coreDataStack.mainContext)
    viewController.user = user
    viewController.viewModel = NewProfileViewModel(for: user, with: coreDataStack)            
}
```

A possible improvement to this is to add and call a method in your view controller that takes all the data that is needed:

```
if segue.identifier == "toNewProfile" {
    var viewController = segue.destination as! NewProfileViewController
    var user = Users ?? Users(context: coreDataStack.mainContext)
    viewController.configureOnSegue(user: user, viewModel: NewProfileViewModel(for: user, with: coreDataStack))            
}
```

where the added view controller method would look like this:

```
func configureOnSegue(user: Users, viewModel: NewProfileViewModel) {
    self.user = user
    self.viewModel = viewModel
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just wanted to avoid `?` optional `viewModel` variables inside of my `NewProfileVC`. That's why I tried to initialise them inside of `init` method

Comment: is using `if let viewModel = self.viewModel {` a good practice?

Comment: Ideally it would be nice to avoid an optional viewModel, but in this case you have to use if let syntax. Another possibility is to assign an empty viewModel as a default. I have used both approaches and prefer to use an optional viewModel.